# Create a custom element in Webform?

Tags: 8, webforms

I am trying to create a custom Webform element that can be added to any webform. It is a select list, but I am providing the options from a remote API call (they cannot be static or hardcoded).

I can get the element to appear in the admin UI with:

```
use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElement\Select;

/**
 * Provides a 'tour type' element.
 *
 * @WebformElement(
 *   id = "tour_type",
 *   label = @Translation("Tour Type"),
 *   description = @Translation("Provides a form element to list tour types from Funnel."),
 *   category = @Translation("Options elements"),
 * )
 */
class TourType extends Select {

}
```

I can add it to a form, and give it options like a regular Select in Webform, but nothing renders on the form.

I was trying to follow this here, but don't quite understand what needs to be done: [Why do my custom elements not get rendered?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296093/why-do-my-custom-elements-not-get-rendered)

Do I need a WebformElement plugin, or a new Element class? I don't see how the two are correlated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a 'Form Element' to process, validate, and render an input and corresponding 'WebformElement' to integrate the input with the Webform module.

You can use the [Webform Example Element](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/-/tree/8.x-5.x/modules/webform_example_element) module as a starting point.

Comment: That is what I followed, eventually I got it. Does the WebformElement id property need to match the FormElement you create? I think that is where I got hung up.

Comment: Yes, the WebformElement and the FormElement need to have the same id.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, if you just want to display static or computed data, here's the most basic webform element:

```php
<?php
namespace Drupal\your_module\Plugin\WebformElement;

use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElement\WebformMarkup;
use Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface;
    

/**
 * Provides a static webform element.
 *
 * @WebformElement(
 *   id = "webform_your_module",
 *   label = @Translation("Human element name"),
 *   description = @Translation("Element description"),
 *   category = @Translation("Choose an existing category or use a new one"),
 *   states_wrapper = TRUE,
 * )
 */
class YourModuleWebformElement extends WebformMarkup {

  /**
   * Optional: only needed if you want to set a human title in the UI
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function defineDefaultProperties() {
    return parent::defineDefaultProperties() + [
        'title' => '',
      ];
  }

  public function isInput(array $element) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function isContainer(array $element) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function prepare(array &$element, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission = NULL) {
    $element['#title'] = '';
    $element[] = [
      '#markup' => 'My text',
    ];
    parent::prepare($element, $webform_submission);
  }

}
```

As  said above, you need matching element

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\your_module\Element;

use Drupal\Core\Render\Element;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Element\FormElement;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Provides an fake element for 'YourModuleWebformElement'.
 *
 * @FormElement("webform_recapitulatif_rac")
 *
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Render\Element\FormElement
 * @see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21FormElement.php/class/FormElement
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderElement
 * @see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/namespace/Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element
 * @see \Drupal\your_module\Element\YourModuleWebformElement
 */
class YourModuleWebformElement extends FormElement {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getInfo() {
    return [
      '#input' => FALSE
    ];
  }

}
```