# Custom webform Element not rendered

Tags: webforms, 10

It looks like this is a frequent question, but I still can not figure out, why my custom webform element is not showing up. (I read already [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296093/why-do-my-custom-elements-not-get-rendered) and also the [example module](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/-/tree/8.x-5.x/modules/webform_example_element))

`web/modules/custom/site_registration/src/Plugin/WebformElement/PersonCountElement.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\site_registration\Plugin\WebformElement;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Annotation\WebformElement;
use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElement\Hidden;
use Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface;

/**
 * Provides a 'site_person_count' element.
 *
 * @WebformElement(
 *   id = "site_person_count",
 *   label = @Translation("Person Count"),
 *   description = @Translation("Provides a fancy person counter."),
 *   category = @Translation("Custom"),
 * )
 *
 * @see \Drupal\webform_example_element\Element\WebformExampleElement
 * @see \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElementBase
 * @see \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElementInterface
 * @see WebformElement
 */
class PersonCountElement extends Hidden {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function prepare(array &$element, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission = NULL) {
    parent::prepare($element, $webform_submission);

    // Here you can customize the webform element's properties.
    // You can also customize the form/render element's properties via the
    // FormElement.
    //
    // @see \Drupal\webform_example_element\Element\WebformExampleElement::processWebformElementExample
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::form($form, $form_state);
    // Here you can define and alter a webform element's properties UI.
    // Form element property visibility and default values are defined via
    // ::defaultProperties.
    //
    // @see \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElementBase::form
    // @see \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElement\TextBase::form
    return $form;
  }


}
```

`web/modules/custom/site_registration/src/Element /PersonCountElement.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\site_registration\Element;

use Drupal\Core\Render\Element\FormElement;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Hidden;

/**
 * Provides a 'site_person_count'.
 *
 * Webform elements are just wrappers around form elements, therefore every
 * webform element must have correspond FormElement.
 *
 * Below is the definition for a custom 'site_person_count' which just
 * renders a simple text field.
 *
 * @FormElement("site_person_count")
 *
 * @see FormElement
 * @see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21FormElement.php/class/FormElement
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderElement
 * @see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/namespace/Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element
 * @see \Drupal\webform_example_element\Element\WebformExampleElement
 */
class PersonCountElement extends Hidden {

  public function getInfo() {
    $properties = parent::getInfo();

    // $properties['#theme'] = 'input__site_person_count';
    return $properties;
  }

}
```

Is there anything more to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was a really stupid mistake! my `src/Element` folder had actually a space in the name.

correct: `src/Element/PersonCountElement.php`
wrong: `src/Element /PersonCountElement.php`

With the correct folder name, it works like a charm.